# Random crashes on Windows PC - ID 6008 unexpected error

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, crash, windows-error-reporting

**The problem:**

My custom PC build(full details below) has started randomly crashing in the last couple of months.

Crashes are seemingly random, sometimes when the PC is completely idle, sometimes when doing something more intensive. Sometimes several times a day, sometimes only once every week.

**PC Specs:**

- OS: Windows 11
- Mother Board: Aorus B550
- Processor: Ryzen 5900x
- GPU: Radeon RX6800
- Audio: Analog Connector (External USB M-Audio Fast Track Pro with ASIO4ALL drivers installed)
- SSD: ADATA SX8200PNP & KINGSTON SKC3000S1024G
- PSU: GIGABYTE Aorus 850W Gold
- RAM: 2x 16GB Kingston KHX3733C19D4*

**What I've Tried so far:**

I've already checked various other forum/reddit/stack overflow posts and internet articles regarding simillar errors. Among the proposed solutions I have:

**Software updates:**

- Clean install of Windows 11, after I was using Windows 10
- Updated all important drivers (GPU,Audio)
- Updated BIOS
- Updated Chipset

**Software debugging:**

- Tried disabling all audio devices
- Ran `chkdsk /F` , 0 bad file records
- Ran `sfc /scannow` (no problems fixed)
- Ran `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth && DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` (no problems etc)
- Used Whocrashed utility to Anylze crash dump files and made sure I enabled crash dumps in windows and set them to `complete memory dump`. After the most recent crash Whocrashed reports no valid crash dumps have been found. Event viewer said: Configuring the Page file for crash dump failed. Make sure there is a page file on the boot partition and that is large enough to contain all physical memory. I'll need to investigate why this happens.
- Looked at Event viewer and recent errors/events around the crash times to see if there's something that could hint at the root cause but to my knowledge there wasn't anything apparent.

**Hardware debugging:**

- Physically re-connected the GPU
- Physically re-connected the CPU fan and applied new thermal paste
- Physically re-isnerted RAM, ensuring it's installed properly
- Monitored components and temperatures using Open Hardware Monitor (nothing temperature wise looks bad)
- Tried connecting the PC to a different electrical outlet
- PC is not in a humid enviornment, it's running in an airconditioned room

**Where do I go from here?**

To me the most likely thing left is the power supply but that seems very werid as it's new and has enough power, maybe it's just my luck. Any basic way to test it ?

Any way to debug this better, maybe install linux?

Comment: Some other things to try: 1. Check drive S.M.A.R.T. status. 2. Try booting and running from USB, e.g. live Ubuntu (see https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) This is very easy to set up, and there is *no* installation. If Ubuntu works well without crashing after some time, you know the issue is either with the SSD or Windows OS. If Ubuntu crashes, too, look to interrupt timing, power supply, etc.

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishePippik, I have checked drive S.M.A.R.T status now and it says OK for all.

I will try installing Linux on a usb stick and booting to it. Problem is these crashes might take up to several days between each one and I need Windows for work related software, so I might not have the chance to do it soon.

Meanwhile, any advice on checking interrupt timing,power supplies and other possible causes?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't advise for a custom PC, but one more check  try stress testing CPU, GPU, SSD and RAM: https://www.wintips.org/how-to-stress-test-cpu-ram-gpu/ . Even SSD's need cooling, and it could be as simple as air flow needing to be rerouted.

Comment: 6008 sounds like the computer is just powering down spontaneously. Arguable, but IMO that isn't a crash *per se*, but it usually implicates the PSU. I presume the PSU is "haswell compatible" but you might check your BIOS for a "dummy load" setting and enable it to see if it is a "deep sleep state" type of issue

Comment: No fixed since then and I wanted to update this thread in case it might be useful to other people somehow:

I have also:
- Installed linux, computer still crashed though much more rarely.  
  
- Swapped the PSU, still crashed
- Swapped the GPU, still crashed
- Added a new SSD and installed Windows on it, still crashed
- Swapped the MotherBoard, still crashed.
- Swapped the RAM and added more
- Re-connected the whole PC

Literally the only thing left is to swap out the PCU, which is the only thing left, which I'll do soon...otherwise its probably a ghost causing these issues :)